# in Android pie-chart is not showing after getting result

Tags: android

In my android project I am using achartengine.jar for viewing piechart ..

the code is:--

```
public class AndroidPopupWindowActivity111_new_made2 extends Activity {

    private static int[] COLORS = new int[] { Color.MAGENTA, Color.CYAN };  
    LinearLayout layout;
    private CategorySeries mSeries = new CategorySeries("");  
    private DefaultRenderer mRenderer = new DefaultRenderer();  
    private GraphicalView mChartView;  
    EditText name1,name2;


    private  int[] VALUES = { 40 , 60 };
     String x1,y1;

     String[] NAME_LIST ; 

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.popup_main);

        mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
        mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(100, 50, 50, 50));  
        mRenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);  
        mRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);  
        mRenderer.setLegendTextSize(15);  
        mRenderer.setMargins(new int[] { 20, 30, 15, 0 });  
        mRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);  
        mRenderer.setStartAngle(90);

        final Button btnOpenPopup = (Button)findViewById(R.id.openpopup);

        mChartView = ChartFactory.getPieChartView(this, mSeries, mRenderer); 


        btnOpenPopup.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
   LayoutInflater layoutInflater    = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext()  .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  


       View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.main_piechart, null);  
             final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow( popupView, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);  
             layout = (LinearLayout)popupView.findViewById(R.id.chart); 
             layout.addView(mChartView);


                 if (mChartView != null) {  

                    mChartView.repaint();  

                 }  


             Button btnDismiss = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.dismiss);
             btnDismiss.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {

      popupWindow.dismiss();
     }});

             popupWindow.showAsDropDown(btnOpenPopup, 50, -30);

   }});
    }

}
```

here I have 2 **edit text** fields.after filling the edit text fields when I click the  **submit button** it is showing the pie-chart..in the piechart there is also a button of dismiss..after click the dismiss button I am going to the previous activity and when again I am filling up the edit text fields and click the submit button the program stops..It is showing error:---

```
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     Process: in.wptrafficanalyzer.achartenginepiechart,  java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. 
You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3718)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3564)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3509)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3485)
```

where is the problem in my code??

Comment: Please add your layout xml as well

Comment: i think the problem with mChartView.repaint();   once remove that line and check it

Comment: No sir,I also removed this..but same error..

Comment: Once print the layout.getChildCount() after adding the layout.addView(mChartView);

Comment: layout.addView(mChartView);
             layout.getChildCount();

same error..java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. 
You must call removeView() on the child's parent first

Answer (score 0):

Add this code

```
 mChartView = ChartFactory.getPieChartView(arg0.getContext(), mSeries,
                    mRenderer);
```

Before

```
layout.addView(mChartView);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it..There was a problem in program logic..by the way thanks for helping